# git: How can I move a branch to an arbitrary commit?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have the following git schema:

[image: git paths]

with the following branches: **mybranch** and **origin/mybranch**, **master** and **origin/master**

Commits **B** and **D** have initially been merged on commit **C** and then they were merged into commit **A**. **mybranch** and **origin/mybranch** point to **A** and **master** and **origin/master** point to **C**.

I would like to have **master** and **origin/master** point to **A** as well, but I don't know how. I have tried `git branch -f master`, but this only moves the **master** branch and diverges it from the remote branch. If I try to run `git branch -f origin/master` to **A**, it does not do anything. This behavior is the same for `git reset --hard` command or even `update-ref`.

Could anybody please tell me what commands should I run such that **master** points to commit A and no other issues are present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these commands:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard A
git push -f origin master
```

After these commands are run master and origin/master will point to **A**.

Note that this will rewrite the history of the master branch, so anyone else who is pulling from this repository will need to rebase.

Comment: Amazing! This was exactly the answer I was looking for. Hats off to you sir.

Comment: You can also combine the first two commands into one: `git checkout -B master A`.